# Is it safe to delete .android folder in my home folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to free up some space on my hard drive. I've noticed that i have .android folder in my home folder on my mac. Does anyone know is it safe to delete this folder? And what exactly is it? It's 10Gb in size. I did use Android Studio on a school project but I don't use it anymore and I've uninstalled Android Studio since then. I don't have any android devices eighter.

Comment: In this folder there is the avd folder that contains the virtual devices. They can hold a lot of space

Comment: If you are no longer doing Android development, this should be safe to remove.

Comment: If you are planning to use Android Studio later - just remove the big device in Android Studio => `Android Virtual Device Manager` (AVD Manager) (the little phone icon on top right) => select device you want to remove, right click on it => `Delete` - this doesn't remove `.android` folder , but removes the GBs of space took by AVD file :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely delete this folder at any time (except maybe while Android Studio is still running!)

All that will happen is that next time you use Android Studio:

- it will need to re-download some stuff.
- you might have to uninstall dev builds of apps on your phone and reinstall them again due to a change in keys.
- you will lose any data and save states of emulators you were using.

Answer (score 1):

Please don`t delete .android because this folder contain some setting that enable app to be installed and run on android emulator or device.

If you delete this folder, apk installation will be rejected during installation in the android device or emulator.

That is what I experienced after delete this folder.

Comment: I am experiencing same thing now as I have accidentally deleted `.android` folder. I am unable to install `apk` into my device. What should I do now?

Comment: for me I restore from trash and work fine

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it is created when you plug an Android device to your computer, and also it is the default location for the AVD as pointed by Gabriele in the comments. Find some insights in the next links:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#data-filedir
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/617912/what-are-the-android-folders-and-adbkey-files-on-my-computer

Cheers!

Comment: This does not answer if it can be removed safely and how will Android Studio react to it.